# Cant get Random to generate number between two numbers

Tags: java

Using this code I have been trying to get a number between them 
*I am using a double so I can use negative numbers*

```
double minX = plugin.getConfig().getDouble("location.min.x");
double maxX = plugin.getConfig().getDouble("location.max.x");
double randomX = random.nextDouble(maxX-minX) + minX;
```

But I get a

```
The method nextDouble() in the type Random is not applicable for the arguments (double)
```

But if I set them to ints it works perfectly fine.

Comment: There simply isn't a method like that. You would've seen this if you would have looked at the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html).

Comment: How am I supposed to get a double between two doubles than?

Comment: If you had a number between 0 and 1, how could you manipulate that mathematically to end up with a number in the range you want such that 0 converts to the bottom of your range and 1 converts to the top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `nextDouble()`,...Returns the next pseudorandom, uniformly
  distributed double value between 0.0 and 1.0 from this random number
  generator's sequence.

So change it to:

```
double randomX = random.nextDouble()*(maxX - minX) + minX;
```

Answer (score 0):

The method: Random.nextDouble(), like Random.nextBoolean() and a few other methods of the Random class, does not take any upper bound arguments.  A common workaround/solution is the one provided by flakes above, ie:

```
double randomX = random.nextDouble()*(maxX - minX) + minX;
```